# NodeJS how to set and get data with only using same module

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, configuration

I have a module to set config. It's working. I want to get config using same module. I don't want to use additional file.

I tried a code something like that:

```
let config_defaults = { test_option: false };

let active_config;
if(active_config === undefined){ active_config = config_defaults };
exports.getcfg = active_config;

const setcfg function(options){
  options = Object.assign({}, config_defaults, options);
  active_config = options;
  return(options);
}; exports.setcfg = select_config;
```

`setcfg` returns changes with no problem. But I can't get changes at `getcfg`. Is it possible to get changes without using additional file?

Outputs:

```
console.log( testmodule.setcfg({test_option: true}) ); /* >> Output: { test_option: true } */

console.log( testmodule.getcfg ); /* >> Output: { test_option: false } */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the issue is that you already assign the reference to an `active_config` object when defining `exports.getcfg`, but later in `setcfg`, `active_config` is *re-assigned* a reference to
a different object.

You could compare the assignment to an object reference as writing down the address of that object in a variable. If you *re-assign* `active_config`, all other variables that knew its previous address still reference that old content.

See e.g. [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

You have 2 easy solutions:

1. Perform a deep mutation: instead of re-assigning the content of `active_config` directly, you change the value of one of its members, as if it was a "routing switch"
2. Make the getter a function, which can then use the most recent version of the scope variable when executed

```js
const exports = testmodule = {};

const config_defaults = {
  test_option: false
};

// Option 1: expose a switch instead of directly the changing variable
const active_config_switch = {
  active_config: config_defaults,
};
exports.getcfg_switch = active_config_switch;

// Option 2: getter as a function
let active_config = config_defaults;
exports.getcfgFn = function() {
  return active_config;
}

const select_config = function(options) {
  options = Object.assign({}, config_defaults, options);
  active_config_switch.active_config = options; // Option 1: deep mutation
  active_config = options;
  return options;
};
exports.setcfg = select_config;

console.log(testmodule.setcfg({
  test_option: true
})); /* >> Output: { test_option: true } */

// Option 1: read the deep member
console.log(testmodule.getcfg_switch.active_config); /* >> Output: { test_option: true } */

// Option 2: execute the getter function
console.log(testmodule.getcfgFn()); /* >> Output: { test_option: true } */
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, It works like a charm. I was thinking javascript can work like java's set and get

Comment: "_javascript can work like java's set and get_": it does, if you use the function form (option 2), or you can even replicate the Java behaviour if you use an object or class to contain your config object (like option 1).

Answer (score 1):

You can totally replicate the Java getter/setter behaviour with [JavaScript class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

```js
const config_defaults = {
  test_option: false
};

/*export*/ class ConfigManager {
  activeConfig = config_defaults;

  getActiveConfig() {
    return this.activeConfig;
  }

  setActiveConfig(options) {
    options = Object.assign({}, config_defaults, options);
    this.activeConfig = options;
    return options;
  }
}

// import { ConfigManager } from "./testmodule";

const configManager = new ConfigManager();

console.log(configManager.setActiveConfig({
  test_option: true
})); // >> Output: { test_option: true }

console.log(configManager.getActiveConfig()); // >> Output: { test_option: true }
```

---

With JavaScript, you do not necessarily need to use a class, especially for a singleton; in this case, an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#defining_methods) is enough:

```js
const config_defaults = {
  test_option: false
};

/*export*/ const configManager = {
  activeConfig: config_defaults,

  getActiveConfig() {
    return this.activeConfig;
  },

  setActiveConfig(options) {
    options = Object.assign({}, config_defaults, options);
    this.activeConfig = options;
    return options;
  }
};

// import { configManager } from "./testmodule";

console.log(configManager.setActiveConfig({
  test_option: true
})); // >> Output: { test_option: true }

console.log(configManager.getActiveConfig()); // >> Output: { test_option: true }
```

---

Still with JavaScript, you can even [hide the getter/setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#defining_getters_and_setters) pattern:

```js
const config_defaults = {
  test_option: false
};

/*export*/ const configManager = {
  _privateActiveConfig: config_defaults,

  get activeConfig() {
    return this._privateActiveConfig;
  },

  set activeConfig(options) {
    options = Object.assign({}, config_defaults, options);
    this._privateActiveConfig = options;
    return options;
  }
};

// import { configManager } from "./testModule";

console.log(configManager.activeConfig = {
  test_option: true
}); // >> Output: { test_option: true }

console.log(configManager.activeConfig); // >> Output: { test_option: true }
```

Comment: That's really helpful. You're rock mate